# How to assign a new value to some memory location in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm trying to access memory location pointed to by (char *addr) and store new value (char val). Here is how I try to do it.

```
int set_new_val(Cmd *cp, char *arguments) {
  char *addr;
  int val;
  if (!sscanf(arguments, "%x %x",&addr,&val))
  {
    return 0;          
  }
  printf("adr = %x || val = %x\n",addr,val);
  *addr = (char)val;
  printf("adr = %x || val = %x\n",addr,*addr);
  return 1;
}
```

Any obvious (or not so) reasons why this wouldn't work is appreciated.

Comment: How doesn't it work?

Comment: http://www.datamation.com/img/2009/07/art-programming.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code might work as expected if the size of `char*` and `int` were the same, as would be the case in 32 bit mode, but not on most modern 64 bit environments.

Another problem you will face in a modern OS (Windows, Linux, OS/X, iOS, android...) is memory protection: you process is only allowed to write to its own data.  It cannot poke values to just any location in memory this way.  Writing to arbitrary memory locations can be achieved using proper execution privileges and the `mmap` function, but it seems well beyond your current skill level.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory for `addr` first, before asigning a value to it:

```
addr = malloc(sizeof(val));
*addr = (char)val;
```

Comment: This does not solve the OP's question.  He wants to implement the plain old Basic POKE function.  Unless he is running on a very rudimentary system, he is unlikely to succeed.

Comment: Nope, he wants to initialize the address with hex data on input.